# Question about the $2\pi$-periodic function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

Suppose that $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $2\pi$ periodic function and consider the ODE
$$(E): y'=(1+\cos(t))y+\phi(t)$$
on $\mathbb{R}$

Suppose here that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a global solution of $(E)$. Show that $f$ is $2\pi$ periodic if and only if $f(0)=f(2\pi)$

This is the question, and I am a little bit confused about the proof of the reverse direction. What I did is like this:

I know by Existness and Uniqueness THM, there must have a unique maximal solution with $f(0)=a$, if $f(0) = f(2\pi)$. Which we can get $f(2\pi)=a$, and I don't really know how to prove $f$ is $2\pi$ periodic.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that with $f(t)$ and its given properties also $g(t)=f(2\pi+t)$ is a solution. This only requires to insert the proposed solution into the equation.

Then for the claim show via the uniqueness theorem that $g$ is identical to $f$ if and only if $f(0)=g(0)=f(2\pi)$.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Its a first order, linear inhomogenous equation  with $2\pi$-periodic coefficients.

The coefficient term
$$\left( t \to    1+\cos t = 2 \ \cos(\frac{t}{2})^2  \right) \ge  0$$
is positive, so without the inhomgenuous term, the homogenuous solution is growing exponentially over any series of complete $2\pi$-intervals.

The the continuation of the solution over the interval $t\in (0,2\pi)$ into the second interval $t\in (2\pi, 4\pi)$ at $t=2\pi$ starts with value $y(2\pi)$.

So the solution is a quasiperiodic function, periodic plus the linear function $t\to \frac{ (y(2\pi)-y(0)} {2\pi}$